# Multi-post in php using jquery seems to fail

Tags: php, jquery

I have an issue with code that I think should be working (the actual code works, it could be a design issue). A user enters something into a form that has to be processed 8 different ways. When done serially (it involves internet look-ups, etc) it just takes too long. So my thought was to trap the submission and launch 8 parallel operations like so:

```
if (process1==true) {
     $.post("dosomething.php",'w=1&i='+input',function(data) {
          (deal with return data, update screen)
     });
}
if (process2==true) {
     $.post("dosomething.php",'w=2&i='+input',function(data) {
          (deal with return data, update screen)
     });
}
if (process3==true) {
     $.post("dosomething.php",'w=3&i='+input',function(data) {
          (deal with return data, update screen)
     });
}
```

Etc.

This is obviously just a stub to demonstrate what's going on. But it captures the way the post calls are being handled (through jQuery).

The call itself to dosomething.php makes a socket call to another server which handles connections using a forking model.

Most of the time it works without issue, however not too infrequently I get errors like "read error". It appears that the connection is being stepped on. Just not sure where or how.

Comment: 1st issue: your `scripts` contain `syntax error`. Mixed single & double quotes.

Comment: `"dosomething.php'` mix of quotes in all of them as well as unmatched. Notice syntax highlighting? You're also missing braces for all your conditionals or have one for each too many. Or, is that deliberate, pseudo-code?

Comment: Appreciate the syntax comments, but I just posted pseudo-code that I typed in for the question. The actual code is syntax-error free, and as I mentioned works most of the time. It's not a syntax problem. The point of the code is to show the method.

Comment: Anything come up in the (error) logs? Plus, are you checking for errors?

Comment: @Fred-ii-Nothing in the error logs. Just the socket processing code which looks like this: while (1) {
                if (false===$chunk=socket_read($socket,8192)) {
                        $this->error=-91;
                        return -1;
                }
                if (strlen($chunk)==0) break;         
                $this->results.=$chunk;
        }               
        socket_close($socket); -- I get the error on the read. Note that if I run the calls serially all works fine.

Comment: Why you posting to the same page three times?  Do you not have control over dosomething.php?  Obviously it'd be better if you combined the three requests into a single request.

Comment: @mick not if you're trying to handle simultaneous operations of varying time length.